# address 0x803e0e of ACS712_ATTINY817.elf section `.data' is not within region `data; ATMEL STUDIO 7

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio

ISSUE: Facing this error on build of from an ATMEL Start project. The project was working earlier but after re-configuring using ATMEL Start i am getting this error.

Can anyone help me in understanding about .elf section in ATMEL Studio 7

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide details on what you have re-configured.

Comment: Hi, I had added a UART driver to my project in ATMEL START online and then imported it to Atmel Studio 7, on build i am getting this error. Is there some issue with my AS 7, i dont know what this error is all about.

Comment: Hello everyone, i just found out that there was some problem with ATMEL STUDIO 7 version that i had, everything worked fine and the above issue is not there, once i re-installed ATMEL Studio on my laptop.